# Ruby: how to read an mp4 file into chunks

Tags: ruby

I want to be able to read an mp4 file in chunks of 1mb.

I've tried opening the file with the following API's:

```
video_file = File.open(@video_filename, 'rb') 
video_file = IO.binread(@video_filename)
```

The problem is, video_file is a string afterwards and I cannot use `read` to get chunks of the file.

```
chunk = video_file.read(4*1024*1024)
```

What is the right interface/tools to use in Ruby to open this file, and read it for N bytes at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose I would do:

```
chnk_size=4*1024*1024
f=File.open(fn, 'rb')
until f.eof?    
    chnk=f.read(chnk_size)
    # process the chnk
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
   `FILENAME = "d:\\tmp\\file.bin"
    MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024

 class File
  def each_chunk(chunk_size = MEGABYTE)
  yield read(chunk_size) until eof?
 end
end

 open(FILENAME, "rb") do |f|
  f.each_chunk { |chunk| puts chunk }
   end`
```

Comment: This isn't really different than what I'm doing above and it monkey patches `File` which I'm not a fan of. Same result either way.